# XPage partial refresh with a script block

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to make my Data View look and feel a bit better, by adding some client side functionality.
In this case I made a script, that let's the user hover over a row and it shows it's detail.
The structure looks something like this:

[image: Structure]

The script block contains some basic jquery:

```
function x$(idTag){
    idTag = idTag.replace(/:/gi, "\\:");
    return("#"+idTag);
}

var dataView = x$('#{id:dataView1}');

var detail;
$(dataView + ' > table > tbody > tr').mouseenter(function (e) {
    detail = $(this).attr('id').replace(':_row', '_detail');
    detail = x$(detail);

    $(detail).show();
});

$(dataView + ' > table > tbody > tr').mouseleave(function () {
    $(detail).hide();
});
```

Everything works fine, until I click on one of the row expand/collapse buttons, at which point the script code stops working.
My guess is it has something to do with the partial refresh, that happens when I expand or collapse a level in the data view, and it doesn't reload the script block or reloads it wrong.
If I turn off partial refresh it keeps working afterward, but of course a full page refresh just to expand or collapse a row is too slow and not realistically usable

Any ideas?

Comment: You most likely have to put your script block inside the area that gets partially refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another source got a quick hack to help here.

Placed both the dataView and scriptBlock in a panel and then set the refreshID of the dataView to the panel's ID.

Comment: Inspired by my comment? :-)

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten another Xpage dev in a Slack chat came up with the idea, but yeah your comment obviously is on the same track. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code only runs on the items it can see on the page - you need to change the selection criteria so that it runs as a delegated event. In this case whenever you move the mouseevent over the data view it will detect the selector which triggered the event and if that matches then it will run accordingly. This way it will run on all rows regardless of whether they were "on the page" before or after the partialRefresh.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Try this instead

```
$(dataView).on ('mouseenter', 'table > tbody > tr', function (e) {
    detail = $(this).attr('id').replace(':_row', '_detail');
    detail = x$(detail);

    $(detail).show();
});

$(dataView).on('mouseleave', 'table > tbody > tr', function () {
    $(detail).hide();
});
```

Code not tested as I don't have your environment :)

Comment: I think you can also make your selector more efficient by looking for the id attribute with :_row in it. Probably won't notice a difference though

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately got the same result. Gonna stick with my own little hack that I posted below, unless someone can provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: Sure - difficult to tell without having the environment - using the delegated events is definitely a way to go to get around partial refresh issues as long as the Script block is not "inside" what is being refreshed :)